# Cannot a return statement containing 2 functions in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return the result of 2 funcs:

```
export function product() {
  const productID= getID();
  const productPrice= getPrice(selectedDeviceId);
  return productID && productPrice;
}
```

The problem is that only the productPrice is returning. I do not need the values from the functions, I just need them to be executed. Both are working correctly as I tested them by writing each of one alone in the return statement. How can I conclude both? Thanks

Comment: You cannot return more than one result from one function. If you really need to do that, then you can return an array or an object with multiple values. I'm not sure that's what you reall need to do that here, though, if you merely need them to be executed. You might need to think over your design a bit.

Comment: Cannot a return statement?

Comment: If you just need to execute the functions than you just call the function, you don't have to return them

Comment: If I can add something: this is not a react question, if you have this kind of missing knowledge you must learn basic JavaScript a bit before digging into react or whatever other library/framewrok. This will save you a lot of time on the mid-long term

Answer (score 1):

```
export function product() {
  const productID= getID();
  const productPrice= getPrice(selectedDeviceId);
  return { productID, productPrice};
}
```

And it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

you could return an array containing your values

```
    export function product() {
  const productID= getID();
  const productPrice= getPrice(selectedDeviceId);
  return [productID, productPrice];
}
```